# How to write tag deleter script in python

Tags: python, parsing, tags, directory

I want to implement a file reader (folders and subfolders) script which detects some tags and delete those tags from the files.

The files are .cpp, .h .txt and .xml And they are hundreds of files under same folder.

I have no idea about python, but people told me that I can do it easily.

**EXAMPLE**:

My main folder is A: C:\A

Inside A, I have folders (B,C,D) and some files A.cpp A.h A.txt and A.xml. In B i have folders B1, B2,B3 and some of them have more subfolders, and files .cpp, .xml and .h....

- xml files, contains some tags like `<!-- $Mytag: some text$ -->`
- .h and .cpp files contains another kind of tags like `//$TAG some text$`
- .txt has different format tags: `#$This is my tag$`

It always starts and ends with $ symbol but it always have a comment character (//,

The idea is to run one script and delete all tags from all files so the script must:

- Read folders and subfolders
- Open files and find tags
- If they are there, delete and save files with changes

**WHAT I HAVE:**

```
import  os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.curdir):

 if files.endswith('.cpp'):
  %Find //$ and delete until next $
 if files.endswith('.h'):
  %Find //$ and delete until next $
 if files.endswith('.txt'):
  %Find #$ and delete until next $
 if files.endswith('.xml'):
  %Find <!-- $ and delete until next $ and -->
```

Comment: what do you have so far?

Comment: I added what I have. Thanks SilentGhost :)

Answer (score 3):

The general solution would be to:

1. use the `os.walk()` function to traverse the directory tree.
2. Iterate over the filenames and use `fn_name.endswith('.cpp')` with if/elseif to determine which file you're working with
3. Use the `re` module to create a regular expression you can use to determine if a line contains your tag
4. Open the target file and a temporary file (use the `tempfile` module). Iterate over the source file line by line and output the filtered lines to your tempfile.
5. If any lines were replaced, use `os.unlink()` plus `os.rename()` to replace your original file

It's a trivial excercise for a Python adept but for someone new to the language, it'll probably take a few hours to get working. You probably couldn't ask for a better task to get introduced to the language though. Good Luck!

----- Update -----

The `files` attribute returned by os.walk is a list so you'll need to iterate over it as well. Also, the `files` attribute will only contain the base name of the file. You'll need to use the `root` value in conjunction with `os.path.join()` to convert this to a full path name. Try doing just this:

```
for root, d, files in os.walk('.'): 
    for base_filename in files: 
        full_name = os.path.join(root, base_filename)
        if full_name.endswith('.h'):
            print full_name, 'is a header!'
        elif full_name.endswith('.cpp'):
            print full_name, 'is a C++ source file!'
```

If you're using Python 3, the print statements will need to be function calls but the general idea remains the same.

Comment: Nice! Any interesting web you know with simple examples? Thanks :)

Comment: Is it possible to do something like fn_name.endswith('.cpp,.h')? Where I do define fn_name?

Comment: Updated to provide a bit more detail. Unfortunately, a quick google search didn't turn up any straight-forward examples. You'll have to play with this a bit to get it figured out. Learning the Python basics is well worth your time though, it'll pay off down the line.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import os
import re

CPP_TAG_RE = re.compile(r'(?<=// *)\$[^$]+\$')

tag_REs = {
    '.h': CPP_TAG_RE,
    '.cpp': CPP_TAG_RE,
    '.xml': re.compile(r'(?<=<!-- *)\$[^$]+\$(?= *-->)'),
    '.txt': re.compile(r'(?<=# *)\$[^$]+\$'),
}

def process_file(filename, regex):
    # Set up.
    tempfilename = filename + '.tmp'
    infile = open(filename, 'r')
    outfile = open(tempfilename, 'w')

    # Filter the file.
    for line in infile:
        outfile.write(regex.sub("", line))

    # Clean up.
    infile.close()
    outfile.close()

    # Enable only one of the two following lines.
    os.rename(filename, filename + '.orig')
    #os.remove(filename)

    os.rename(tempfilename, filename)

def process_tree(starting_point=os.curdir):
    for root, d, files in os.walk(starting_point): 
        for filename in files:
            # Get rid of `.lower()` in the following if case matters.
            ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower()
            if ext in tag_REs:
                process_file(os.path.join(root, base_filename), tag_REs[ext])
```

Nice thing about `os.splitext` is that it does the right thing for filenames that start with a `.`.